# Javascript pm2 fails to persist my scripts at RPI boot time

Tags: gpio, boot, boot-issues, javascript

I do this to make my scripts run on Raspbian start:

```
sudo pm2 startup ubuntu
sudo pm2 start my_script.js
sudo pm2 start another_script.js
```

Yet, RPi starts without them, what can be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Setup pm2 for Raspberry:

```
sudo env PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin pm2 startup systemd -u pi --hp /home/pi
```

Add your script:

```
pm2 start my_script.js
```

Save pm2 table for reboot:

```
sudo pm2 save
```